# What exactly is "oxidation state"?

Tags: covalent-compounds

the textbooks say that it is the amount of electrons lost or gained by an atom in a bond but in a covalent molecule the atoms never technically lose electrons ,instead share them to in such a way to complete their octet.for eg:- In OF2 molecule, it is said that the oxidation state of oxygen is +2 which implies it has lost 2 electrons. However it also must be gaining electrons from the other flourine atoms, right? please help me out with this.

Comment: The oxidation state is indeed the amount of electrons lost or gained by an atom _in case of some highly contrived and artificial process which never really happens_.

Comment: Whatever we say it is, maybe?

Comment: I don't understand at all

Comment: For calculation all those bond are treated as if there were ionic.